# Using const Array inside html tags in php

Tags: php

```
const EMOJI = [
    ":lol" => "http://localhost/chat/emoji/0046.gif",
    ":D" => "http://localhost/chat/emoji/0055.gif"
]
```

i want to use

> EMOJI[:lol]

in src can anybody tell me how should i use it ?

```
case ":lol":
    echo "<img src='EMOJI[:lol]' width='32' height='32'>";
break;
```

Comment: I think quotation is the problem. Use the following:
case ":lol":
   $emo = EMOJI[':lol'];
    echo "<img src='$emo' width='32' height='32'>";
break;

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape quotes here. You can use like this:

```
echo "<img src='".EMOJI[':lol']."' width='32' height='32'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like that:

```
echo "<img src='" . EMOJI[':lol'] . "' width='32' height='32'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Array key should be integer or string so you should use `EMOJI[':lol']` instead of `EMOJI[:lol]`;

**Example**

```
case ":lol":
    echo "<img src='".EMOJI[':lol']."' width='32' height='32'>";
break;
```